# Formatting GridPane to have different background color in one row

Tags: java, javafx-2

```
gridPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #C0C0C0;");
```

Works and sets the background color of the whole gridpane, but how do I set it for a certain row, eg. row 5?

Do I need to use stylesheets for this? I'd prefer to do it in Java.

**EDIT:** each row contains a label, but the label does not cover the whole row in a pane. If I could set the label to cover the whole row and then set the background color of the label that would be a workaround.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can add to each grid cell new Pane() object and set background to it.